# How to store file and images in google cloud storage using java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my application i need to store media files in google cloud storage. I used Google cloud storage API but it is not working. If anyone have goo tutorial or documentation (except google documentation) . Can you share with me.

Comment: What have you tried? What error did you get?

Comment: @ParagJadhav I use code in this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage. but it is not working. When i am trying to pass file name and bucket. It shows that file name doesn't available. But it is available.